# Angular AuthorizeGuard Roles

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to implement a role based system on my application and I have the following:

**authorize.service.ts**

```
  public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getUser().pipe(map(u => !!u));
  }

  public hasRole(roles: Array<string>): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getUser().pipe(map(u => {
      if (!!!u) {
        return false;
      }
      const role = u['http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role'];
      return roles.some(r => r === role);
    }));
  }
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
...
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent, canActivate: [AuthorizeGuard], data: { title: 'List', roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Developer, Role.Guest, Role.User]} }
...
```

And I would like to have the following logic on my **AuthorizeGuard**:

If isn't authenticated navigate to the login page.

If is logged in and has the required role navigate to the page otherwise navigate to a "forbidden" page.

I have this code on my canActivate:

```
  canActivate(
    _next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    this.authorize.isAuthenticated().subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        this.authorize.hasRole(roles).subscribe(hasRole => {
          if (hasRole) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['forbidden']);
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(ApplicationPaths.LoginPathComponents, {
          queryParams: {
            [QueryParameterNames.ReturnUrl]: state.url
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work because of the subscribers.

Is there anyway to make wait for the result and return it instead of always return true?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are almost there. If your user is already authenticated, i would suggest you store that in localStorage, Cookie, or Rx.BehaviorSubject. Then you first check if the user is authenticated by checking if the local storage token exsits with the correct data (e.g. Roles). If the login token does not exsist, navigate to forbidden. If it exists, then move on to check if the correct roles are applied and continue with the proper action. side note: Checking the correct roles on each auth hit is quite a costly operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix 2 subscribe and return true in the end, cause it always is true(last return).

You need return `Observable<boolean>` from the start and chain it to have Observable of `false || true` at the end

This code is changed in this editor, so it maybe won't work from the start, but you would get the idea of chaining

```
return this.authorize.isAuthenticated().pipe(
  concatMap(isAuth => isAuth ? this.authorize.hasRole(roles) : throwError('NO_AUTH')),
  concatMap(hasRole => hasRole ? of(true) : throwError('NO_ROLE')),
  catchError(error => {
    const isAuthError = error === 'NO_AUTH';
    if (isAuthError) {
      this.router.navigate(ApplicationPaths.LoginPathComponents, {
        queryParams: {
          [QueryParameterNames.ReturnUrl]: state.url
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['forbidden']);
    }

    return of(false);
  }),
);
```

p.s approach with `catchError` could be reworked to some other

Comment: code is not so smart, so it sees 'return true' and executes it without care about subscribes. it got boolean, so he won't look for Promise | Observable